# Graph data science library install issue

Tags: neo4j, gdscript

I had a problem installing the GDS library of neo4j. I followed the steps in [this tutorial](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/1.8/installation/neo4j-server/), but when I wanted to verify the installation using the last two  commands `Return gds.version()`  worked but `CALL gds.list` doesn't work and shows me this error:

[image]

I have windows 7 and a neo4j server community edition (4.4.5).

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you do add this configuration on the file located in  <NEO4J_HOME>/conf/neo4j.conf

```
# A comma separated list of procedures and user defined functions that are allowed
# full access to the database through unsupported/insecure internal APIs.
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=gds.*
```